# In Xamarin Forms how to make every custom picker preselect the only option if there is only one?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

We have hundreds dropdowns that are using the same ui control (ContentView) that by its turn uses a bindable picker class.

The business wants that every dropdown comes pre-filled if there is only one item in the list. It makes no sense making the user choose from only one option.

Now, we could do this in every page OnAppearing event that uses this control but there a hundreds...

The idea solution would be to make the control intelligent enough to know there is only one option and then preselect it.

I managed to do this in the bindable picker class but, although the item is selected the property in the page remains null and the validation says it is null, even though it isn't...

Is there a way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
    static void OnItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
    {
        if (Equals(newValue, null) && Equals(oldValue, null))
        {
            return;
        }

        var picker = (BindablePicker)bindable;

        picker._disableNestedCalls = true;
        picker.Items.Clear();
        picker._disableNestedCalls = false;

        if (!Equals(newValue, null))
        {
            var hasDisplayMemberPath = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(picker.DisplayMemberPath);

            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)newValue)
            {
                if (hasDisplayMemberPath)
                {
                    var type = item.GetType();
                    var prop = type.GetRuntimeProperty(picker.DisplayMemberPath);
                    picker.Items.Add(prop.GetValue(item).ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    picker.Items.Add(item.ToString());
                }
            }
            picker._disableNestedCalls = true;


            // PICKER FOUND ONLY ONE ITEM!!!!!!!
            if (picker.Items.Count == 1)
            {
                picker.SelectedIndex = 0;
                foreach (var item in picker.ItemsSource)
                {
                    picker.SelectedItem = item;
                    var type = item.GetType();
                    var prop = type.GetRuntimeProperty("Identifier");
                    picker.SelectedValue = prop.GetValue(item);
                    break;
                }
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                picker.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }

            picker._disableNestedCalls = false;

            if (picker.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                picker.InternalSelectedItemChanged();
            }
            else if (hasDisplayMemberPath && picker.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                picker.InternalSelectedValueChanged();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            picker._disableNestedCalls = true;
            picker.SelectedIndex = -1;
            picker.SelectedItem = null;
            picker.SelectedValue = null;
            picker._disableNestedCalls = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom picker class that overrides the base Items property to check the count of the list when setting the items and, if count == 1, set the SelectedIndex to 0;

Like so:

```
class MyPicker : Picker
{
    public new List<string> Items
    {
        get => base.Items;
        set 
        {
            base.Items = value;

            if (value.Count == 1)
                SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this, you only need to change the references of Picker to MyPicker in your code.

You will need to create a bindable property if you plan to use with XAML but it should be pretty easy and there's plenty of material about how to do that if you don't know.

Obs. I wrote the code without any correction, so it could need simple adjustments.

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a converter on the picker you're binding.
I'm not sure that's what you're seeking but might be a solution.
I got something like that to pre-set my picker from an object (Hydrating a form from an object)

```
Picker.SetBinding(Picker.TitleProperty, "ListOfObject", BindingMode.Default, new ListObjectConverter());
```

And in your converter you can do something like that :

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null) return "";
            var listObject = (List<Object>)value;
            if (listObject.Count == 0)
                return "";

            return listObject.Aggregate("", (current, object) => current + (object.Name + " "));
        }
```

This way you can handle populating you're picker with the only option you got in picker (the first one in the list I guess for your case)

Comment: Thanks very much, this looks promising. However I don't know how to use a convertrer very well yet. Can I do it in XAML instead of Picker.SetBinding?

Comment: Yep sorry forgot I was using pure c# for my project. So I guess you can do something like that : 

 `<Picker x:Name="YourPicker" Title = "{Binding ListOfObject, Converter={converters:ListObjectConverter}}" />`